# egrep warning: egrep is obsolescent; using egrep -E

Tags: linux, mysql, grep

could someone help me with the problem I had when installing and starting xampp, it shows me this error.  (Arch-Linux)

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
XAMPP: Starting Apache...egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
ok.
```

Comment: it says it's a warning, not an error so what's the problem?

Comment: I understand, sorry. That problem came out when I wanted to start xampp. 

#opt/lampp/lampp start

 XAMPP: Starting Apache...egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
already running.

so with the others. (MySql-ProFTPD)

Comment: Any special reason to use Xampp?